# Get Route parameter from group route in SLIM 3 PHP

Tags: php, slim-3

I am having issue getting the group route parameter in middleware here's what i am doing

I am using [**[PHP - SLIM 3 Framework](http://slimframework.com)**]

> route.php

```
$app->group('/{lang}', function() use ($container){
   //routes ... (ignore the other routes)
})->add(new Middleware($container));
```

> Middleware.php

```
//middleware.php
class Middleware {
   public function __invoke($req, $res, $next)
   {
      //here is the part which is confusing about how can i get 
      // {lang} parameter
      $req->getAttribute('route')
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `getArguments()`-method

```
public function __invoke($req, $res, $next)
{
    $route = $req->getAttribute('route');
    $args = $route->getArguments();
    $lang = $args['lang'];

    return $res;
}
```

Note: you also need to set the slim setting `determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware` to true. Otherwise the argument is not set in the middleware.

```
$container = [
    'settings' => [
        'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true
    ]
]
$app = new \Slim\App($container);
```